# VS Code creates a local copy of a remote branch every time I switch to it

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, local, checkout

VS Code keeps creating local copy of a remote branch at every time I checkout from the remote branch but I don't want this, because it creates a mess in the panel with same named branches all over the panel. I don't want this and only want to track the changes remotely. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Git: Checkout to (Detached)` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) instead of `Git: Checkout to` or the quick pick menu that appears when you click the head indicator in the status bar. If you want to bind a keyboard shortcut to that command, its ID is `git.checkoutDetached`.

If you're interested in the history of how this feature came to be, this was raised as a feature request before for there to be a way to checkout without creating a local tracking branch: [Option to disable creation of a branch when a remote tracking branch is selected #96264](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96264). The feature was released in [the November 2020 (1.52) release of VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52).

Though note that (according to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96264#issuecomment-739772782),) the status bar indicator of the current HEAD will show the commit hash instead of the remote branch name.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found that issue ticket by googling "`github vscode issues checkout remote branch without creating local tracking branch`".